# adb connection to android things raspberry pi not possible

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, adb

I've been trying for hours to connect my Android Things Raspberry Pi to Android Studio via adb.

I can ping the pi and I can also see on my TV, which is connected via HDMI to my pi, that the pi works. Firstly I tried to connect the Pi via USB but then I read that couldn't work, so I tried to connect via adb.

I entered the command 'adb connect "ip adress"'(in my case 192.168.178.20) in my cmd but it said it was unable to connect because the destination computer refused to connect.

I also tried to connect to my phone but there was the same error.

Because I thought there was a problem with my firewall I tried to connect via the  mobile hotspot network of my phone; it brought the same error.

What could I have done wrong?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Hi,

the adb connection to my phone and my tab works for some reason now; however the connection to my pi is still not working.

Comment: I'm sorry, i solved the problem; I accidentally downloaded the production image, not development image.